# How can I initialize a member object of a class in constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

For clarity consider the example below :

```
class A{
    public:
        A(int i){...}
}

class B{
    private:
        A A_instance;
    public:
        B(){
           ...
           //how can i initialize the A_instance with specific constructor ?
           ...
        }
}
```

I think, you get what is my problem (lack of knowledge:D). how can i initialize the A_instance with specific constructor in class B?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the constructor initialization list, that is the only way to explicitly initialize a data member.

```
B() : A_Instance(42) 
{
  // by the time we get here, all data members have been initialized
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a previous comment noted, you use the initializer list, and not inside the constructor body. This is good because then it is A_instance is initialized when created rather than afterwards.

```
class A{
    public:
        A(int i){...}
}

class B{
    private:
        A A_instance;
    public:
        B() : A_instance(0) {
           ...
           ...
        }
}
```